# Difference between glColor3f and glColor3d

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

The code I'm working on, in a nutshell, uses OpenGL to represent data (stored as double) as the colour of some geometry. Using the default colour shading between vertices it then samples back the colour over the geometry to see the values at different pixels and convert them back to my data. Currently it's done using 1D texture mapping, such that any value I draw and sample back can be exactly located on a scale. However since the data I'm working with is stored as a double, a lot of precision is lost when all values drawn and sampled back are mapped on a 14-bit texture map.

So to address that issue, now I'm implementing the code using floating-point colour.
I'm using an FBO with a GL_RGBA32F renderbuffer colour attachment. The thing which I don't understand is **what will change if I set the colour of my vertices using glColor3d versus glColor3f**.
If I'm understanding correctly, with a single precision floating point renderbuffer, the values I sample back for RGB will basically be GLfloat type, not GLdouble.

Also, is there any way I can configure my renderbuffer such that I can draw with GLdouble colour values and be able to sample back GLdouble values? Looking at the [OpenGL 4.5 spec p198](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf) there aren't any colour formats with more than 32f precision per clour channel. From my understanding, double precision colour is fairly modern tech only supported on newer systems, which only confuses me more about the presence of glColour3d.

Comment: You are correct the values drawn into the FBO will be 32bit float.

Comment: FP64 support is more to do with calculations supported in shaders. However from my experience accuracy of sin/cos etc vary between GPU's.

Comment: current GPU's lack a lot of stuff for fully support 64bit floating points for example there are no 64bit interpolators so even if you pass 64 bit data to vertex you can not pass them as interpolators (varying in/out) to fragment. There is a workaround which divides the double `d` into 2 floats `f0,f1` where `f0=float(d);  f1=float(d-double(f0));` so you can do the same for your rendering target and render to 2 textures ... if you want the double again just do `d = double(f0)+double(f1);`

Comment: this trick will not increase the exponent range but double the mantissa bits ... its still less than double but not that much. If you want full precision then use 3 variables in the same way `f0,f1,f2` that is more mantissa bits than in double